# Configure GUI and VNC on Ubuntu 20.04, Server for Oracle Cloud Instance

Tags: 20.04, gui, vnc, oracle

I am newbie for servers. I want to to configure GUI and VNC server on ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I am having free instance on Oracle Cloud.
I had tried from several links which is for lower version of ubuntu but those leads to error

Thank you in Advance

Comment: What do you mean by gui? if you're running ubuntu server, I dunno. As far as vnc server, there are many on apt. `apt search vnc | less`

Answer (score 0):

Try `gnome-remote-desktop`(gui) for the client. I believe it may solve both of your issues at once. It is a vnc server that provides a desktop. As it is from apt, dependencies (i.e. gnome-desktop, a.k.a. GUI) will be taken care of as well.

You just type the command into the terminal:

```
sudo apt install gnome-remote-desktop
```

For Gnome desktop on the server itself (if it has a monitor):

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

The first will likely install the second automatically.

Comment: thanks @Nate, This will help us to install GUI and i want to config this gui with VNC server. I got Blank Display after config VNC server

Comment: Does the server have local monitor access, or are you wanting the gui just for viewing via vnc remote host. The The second app is the difference between normal Ubuntu (called Ubuntu Desktop) and Ubuntu Server. Ubuntu Server + ubuntu-gnome-desktop = regular old ubuntu (at least for the last few years, anyway. It used to be Unity.) I'm pretty sure the first app just gives a gnome GUI to the remote host (if that is your main interface to the server, then this is perfect!) but it may automatically install the first as well. It seems like a feature extension of it.

Comment: I use Vnc viewer to access server over SSH connection. Yes i am using ubuntu server only but i install Gui using Terminal. The command is pretty much same as your answer

Comment: What vnc server did you go with?

Comment: After installing gnome-remote-desktop ... then what?